# Is there any good OpenDocument library in ruby?

Tags: ruby, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I would like to generate a OpenDocument format in Ruby programming language.

Something like [prawn](http://github.com/sandal/prawn) but for OpenDocument.

Is there any good library for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Documatic](http://documatic.240gl.org/)

> Documatic is an OpenDocument processor for Ruby

Answer (score 0):

[Rspreadsheet](https://github.com/gorn/rspreadsheet) for Open Document spreadsheets. It can read, modify and write osd files.